# Theorems via tcolorbox + translator package gives error with CTAN-updated TeX Live

Tags: errors, tcolorbox, translator

I am using TeX Live 2021 (actually MacTeX-2021), with all current updates from CTAN installed via the TeX Live Utility. The following minimal working example results in an error message (see below):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{translator}
\newtranslation[to = German]{Theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem{theorem}{\translate{Theorem}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}{}{}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

The relevant (first two) error messages from the log file seem to be the following:

```
Use of \@undeclaredcolor doesn't match its definition.
\kernel@ifnextchar ...rved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.10 \begin{theorem}{}{}

Use of \\translate  doesn't match its definition.
\kernel@ifnextchar ...d@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}
                                                  \def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...
l.10 \begin{theorem}{}{}
```

The error does not appear on a vanilla TeX Live 2020. I assume it does also not appear on a vanilla TeX Live 2021 (without current updates from CTAN), but I cannot easily test this on my system. In fact, I think the error did not occur until some update from CTAN within the last 2 months or so, but I cannot be sure.

If I exchange `\translate{Theorem}` with `Theorem` the document compiles without problems. Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: tcolorbox fully expands the argument with `\tl_set:Nx` and this doesn't work. Imho it is a bug in tcolorbox. I will open an issue.

Comment: issue opened https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/165

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer for pointing at the likely culprit and opening the issue.

Comment: btw You can use `\newtcbtheorem{theorem}{\unexpanded{\translate{Theorem}}}{}{}` as a workaround.